# How To Bring Back A User (Person 1, Person 2) That Got Deleted In Google Chrome Settings?

Tags: google-chrome

October 15, 2014, I went to Google Chrome Settings to change the settings of the new tab page. however, due to having had enough of the constant crashing, I deleted everything that seemed irrelevant to me including a few extensions and the worst part is, I deleted the "Person 1" stuff in the "People" section of Chrome Settings which led to the deletion of bookmarks, passwords, caches, cookies, etc. I've searched for ways and nothing has helped so far.

please don't ignore this question. I'm really desperate since one of the bookmarks that got deleted is the link to the private chatroom I have with my best friend and I've been damn dead worried for a week now.

Comment: If it's deleted it's likely gone for good unless you synced to the cloud. Can't you just ask your friend for the link again?

Comment: try to see in the recycle bin.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on SuperUser.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to recover your bookmarks that I found to be extremely useful and easy. Basically, I accidentally deleted my 'Person 1' from Chrome. I was not logged in so there was no way to restore those files until I found this link.

1. Paste C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data into the file explorer
2. Locate the Bookmarks.bak file and relocate it to a safe place (I used the desktop)
3. Open this link in your Chrome browser: https://rongjiecomputer.github.io/chrome/bookmark-recovery/#windows
4. Drag your file into the *Drag Your File* section of the page and bingo! From there, you will have to manually re-bookmark the pages to your browser.

Hope this helped anyone. I know it did a great deal for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to do it !
But I did it immediately. Maybe this could help other people in desperation like I was.

First close Chrome and go to:
**C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data**

I found the folder :
**"Default"**
Right click on it **> Properties > Previous Versions**

And there you should have previous versions of that folder (hopefully you had it enable). For more info go to:
[Windows Previous Versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7)

Then choose a recent one before you deleted the **"Person 1"** and click on "Restore".

Then I had another folder in the same directory called : 
**"Profile 1"**

Which I assume is the actual one, without any info as you deleted the old profile.

Then you just delete all the content of the "Profile 1" folder and copy all the content of the **"Default"** folder.

That's it ! You recovered all your previous data, bookmarks, passwords, etc.

Hopefully this will help other people.

Comment: I had no `Default` folder.  So I restored the entire `User Data` folder.  Very successful!

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you'll have to go to the recycle bin. There you'll find the deleted chrome hopefully. This happened to me and I nearly got a heart attack. Just restore it from there and you're good to go! Hope this helps!